# Show multiply module metrics on a common Sonar dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

I would like to show multiply module metrics on a common Sonar dashboard with free or dafault available widget. Is that possible?

We use SonarQube Version 5.6.3.

Comment: Be aware, that the dashboard has been removed in SonarQube 6.1. Your efforts might be lost, when you want to upgrade to a more recent version of SonarQube.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. You are correct: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+6.1+Upgrade+Notes